# SUSY vs bosonization and fermionization

Tags: fermions, supersymmetry, bosonization

(New to the concepts.)

From what was known SUSY described a theory consisted of both a boson and a fermion pair as a symmetric counter part. Bosonization and Fermionization on the other hand described a theory of boson or fermion expressed in the language of fermion or boson.

Though being somewhat very different topics, was there any connection between those two concepts in the dynamics? For example, in SUSY, the operators used to convert the bases between the boson and the fermion was used to construct the Hamiltonian, which seemed to be a strong indication(or diversion).

Comment: This post (v1) seems quite broad. A theory with both bosons and fermions is not necessarily supersymmetric.

Comment: @Qmechanic My advisor told me the same thing and I felt so. It's just that the symmetry of the Hilbert space states(SUSY) and the symmetry of the dynamics(bosonization and fermionization) might have something more to say. For example, the electric field and the magnetic field, if thinking them as symmetric correspondence of the classical states, the dynamics (electric or magnetic interaction) in some cases could be converted through Lorentz symmetry. I was wondering if SUSY could be such quantum mechanical illustration.

Answer (score 2):

Bosonization/Fermionization and supersymmetry refer to entirely different concepts.

1. A supersymmetric theory is a theory whose symmetry algebra is a [supersymmetric extension of the Poincaré algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincar%C3%A9_algebra). The "odd" or "fermionic" operators in this algebra send bosonic states to fermionic states and vice versa. That is, the space of states of this theory contains *both* bosonic and fermionic states and there is a symmetry transformation that maps those into each other.
2. Bosonization/Fermionization refers to *two distinct theories*, one containing bosonic states/fields and the other fermionic states/fields as its elementary building blocks. There is an equivalence between the theories, i.e. some sort of invertible map that sends one theory to the other and preserves all the features we care about. The bosonic theory is the bosonization of the fermionic theory, the fermionic theory is the fermionization of the bosonic theory. There is no supersymmetry even potentially here because the bosonic and fermionic states do not exist "at the same time" - bosonization is a "duality", a map between two at first glance different theories, while supersymmetry is just a symmetry operator.

Comment: But in the case of the Bosonization/Fermionization was there a "marginal"/transitional case? For example, a pure electric field and a pure magnetic field in the classical physics sometimes could be seen as two limit of the boost(say a group element $g$). I was thinking that they looked like the SUSY's states correspondence, i.e. $g|e\rangle=|m\rangle$. Thus, one can compute them as rather separate components in one theory, or "electricnization/magnatization" in the two limit. But there there was also transitional cases with some extra group elements that's more interesting.Thus,how about SUSY?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate I don't understand your comment. Electro-magnetic duality is  not a map between two different theories since there is no consistent theory of *only* the electric or *only* the magnetic field, nor does it have anything to do with fermions.

Comment: Bosonization and fermionization only being applicable when your theory is 100% one or the other is too strong a claim: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04378

Comment: @ConnorBehan I think this more a terminology issue than a disagreement about the physics: what that paper calls "bosonization" is a generalization of a "true" bosonization between "CS+fermion" <-> "CS+boson" to "CS+fermion/boson" <-> different "CS+fermion/boson". Much like a "manifold with corners" isn't a "manifold", I'd argue this notion of "generalized bosonization" isn't actually "bosonization" (without the history as a generalization, why would we call a duality between theories with the same number of bosons/fermions "bosonization"?).